# What is wrong with my key.properties file in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to edit my key.properties file to point to the upload-keystore.jks file.  For some reason flutter is giving me an error for the \upload section of the code.  The error is "Invalid unicode code points".  Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

[picture of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhLkj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhLkj.png)

I tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Please add your path using forward slash. Like: C://Users/jdevo

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like an idiot!

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was a mistake in the use of the backslash () instead of the forward slash (/)